# Postgres autovacuum stops working after relfrozenxid age hits autovacuum_freeze_max_age

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

We use postgres 11 in Azure cloud as a temporary store. Two tables in particular receive large number of inserts and deletes (hundreds of millions) in lots of small transactions with heavy lock contention during our batch processing. The tables will eventually be empty when all the data is processed. Because of the amount of traffic going through these two tables we have tuned autovacuum to be aggressive on them
`autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit=2000, autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=1, autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.02, autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000`

Autovacuum generally keeps up with the load and keeps the table size down. We also sometimes truncate or run `vacuum full` between loads. But once in a while we are noticing that the autovacuum process stops running completely. Around the same time we start seeing xid wraparound warnings in the logs. When this happens `relfrozenxid` age for some `pg_catalog` tables is over 200 million but not for the tables we are using.

Autovacuum doesn't come back even if we leave the database in a quiet state for a few hours. `pg_stat_progress_vacuum` shows no activity. `pg_stat_activity` does not show any long running transactions. There are no abandoned replication slots or prepared transactions that could block autovacuum. We can't vacuum tables in `pg_catalog` because it is owned by azure super user. We also don't have access to see if autovacuum threads are running at the os level.

Restarting postgres gets the autovacuum going again but it is not a viable option for us in the long run.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Please share the log messages.  pg_stat_progress_vacuum show no rows, or has rows that don't seem active?

Answer (score 0):

When your tables stop being vacuumed, you should check how many autovacuum workers you see in `pg_stat_activity`. If there are as many as `autovacuum_max_workers`, the explanation is that there is no room for your tables being `VACUUM`ed. Anti-wraparound autovacuum may well cause that, since those runs are normally longer and more resource-intense than normal autovacuum runs.

You can either speed up the anti-wraparound autovacuum workers by setting the parameters appropriately, or you can increase `autovacuum_max_workers` to avoid starving your important tables. Both options will make autovacuum use more of your system's resources.

Comment: I don't think anti-wraparound autovacuum is kicking in because we hardly see any IO or CPU usage when database hits this state. We even left the database overnight with zero usage to see if it would recover, but it hasn't. All we see is a continues stream of 'oldest xmin is far in the past' warnings filling up the logs. If we resume data ingestion, normal autovacuum doesn't kick in anymore. pg_stat_all_tables shows dead tuple ratio going up, tables size going up but autovacuum_count not changing.

Comment: Also I don't remember seeing any rows related to vacuuming in pg_stat_activity when this happens.

Comment: You didn't have a lot of hard data in your question, so there's some speculation in my answer. Besides, since this is on Azure, which means that PostgreSQL was hacked up in undisclosed ways, it might be something entirely different that only Microsoft can tell you. I suggest asking them (good luck).